# Delete certain filetype, based on filename

Tags: windows, file, sorting, types

So i have a folder which contains a lot of subfolders ( about 1000 )
Those subfolders has .bmp .jpg .png and .tga files.

I need to delete all the .tga files **IF** :

in the same (sub)folder there **is** same named .jpg or .png file

**Example**

Folder1

- street.bmp
- street.png
- street.tga <-- **delete tga because of .png**

Folder2

- road.bmp
- road.tga <-- **do NOT delete tga because there is not same named .png or .jpg file, only .bmp**

  *

(Every folder has those .bmp files which are always named the same as the tga files)

I really hope to get a solution, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. 
Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: In case you are not familiar with `powershell`- It is Microsoft's replacement for `Dos` type `command prompt`. So you can run `powershell` from your programs menu, copy-paste the solution I have provided below, hit enter twice - and the scrip will run...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is `powershell` script:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse "C:\MyFolder" -Include @("*.png","*.jpg") | 
Foreach-Object {

$strName=$_.BaseName+".tga"
$pngFile=$_.FullName   
$tgaFile=$_.DirectoryName+"\"+$strName

If (Test-Path $tgaFile){
  Remove-Item $tgaFile  
}

}
```

In a nutshell: find all `.png` or `.jpg` files (recursively) and for each one check if `.tga` exists. If exists delete it.

Comment: This worked like a charm the first time i tried it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with two batch file commands using the FOR command:

Type "FOR /?" from the Command Prompt to see the command syntax:

First change to the directory containing your pictures:

```
C:\> cd /d "D:\Pictures"
D:\Pictures>
```

Then inside your "D:\Pictures" folder, run these two commands:

```
for /r %f in (*.tga) do if exist "%~df%~pf%~nf.png" del "%f"
for /r %f in (*.tga) do if exist "%~df%~pf%~nf.jpg" del "%f"
```

Please be careful when testing commands like this and preferably after making good backup!  You've been warned.

Breakdown of the commands:
for (for command)

```
/r      Recurse subdirectories
%f      Variable used to represent each matching file
(*.tga) File Spec to search for
do       part of for command, following command executed for each match
if exist XXX del XXX

~d between the %f (%~df), returns only the drive (d:)
~p between the %f (%~pf), returns only the path (\path\)
~n between the %f (%~nf), returns only the filename without extension
...then appending .png or .jpg to end of those...
~f returns the full filename, including path
```

Also, if you need to put a command like this inside a batch file, you need to double up the percent signs on the variable name, like:

```
for /r %%f in (*.tga) do if exist "%%~df%%~pf%%~nf.png" del "%%f"
for /r %%f in (*.tga) do if exist "%%~df%%~pf%%~nf.jpg" del "%%f"
```

Comment: I managed to delete only 1 file with this, and 19 more when i removed the /r variable. I checked the folders and it seems like it deleted only pictures that were directly under the main 'Pictures' folder. But like i said, that 'Pictures' folder has almost 1000 subfolders inside, and this commandline has to reach there too.

Comment: @user6681334, I updated my answer, I forgot to include drive letter (%~df).  Let me know if that still doesn't work.

Comment: This time it does something little more longer, and I can see the path and the name of the tga files flashing ( like last time ). However I can barely see a message between the lines flashing saying something like "Can't find specified file" I checked the folder size and it remained the exact same.

Comment: @user6681334, What version of Windows are you running?  Also, try to output the files to a text files using:  for /r %f in (*.tga) do echo %~df%~pf%~nf.png >> C:\FileList.txt    Are the files in that C:\FileList.txt valid filenames, or what is wrong?

Comment: Windows 10. I tried echoing them and I got the right filenames. ( Although it echoed them as .png when it searched .tga

Comment: @user6681334: Ah, the problem may be your folders or filenames contain spaces and they aren't quoted.  Try updated commands above.

Comment: I get error "%%f was unexpected at this time." I tried removing one % from it, and the folder size did not change, ie. no files were deleted.